# ADF - Unable to read view Id of Declarative Component from "var" of af:iterator

Tags: oracle-adf

I am facing a weird issue where when i assign "var" of af:iterator to the view Id of declarative component, it is saying "  Encountered null from the viewId expression: #{row}"

And Page is showing blank.

My JSPX code is as follows :

```
<af:iterator value="#{pageFlowScope.stageBean.pathList}" var="row">

<af:outputText value="#{row}" id="ot1"/>

<af:declarativeComponent viewId="#{row}"/>

</af:iterator>
```

And code snippet for getter in Java bean is as follows:

```
public List<String> getPathList()
{
List<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
pathList.add("/Test.jspx");
return pathList;
}
```

The weird thing here is output text is printing the path /Test.jspx but declarative component is not recognizing it. Its showing blank page and in logs, error says "Encountered null from the viewId expression: #{row}"

If i remove #{row} from viewId and manually give like viewId = "/Test.jspx" , its displaying the page correctly.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Regards,
Rakesh.

Comment: can you try if declarativeComponents work with EL expression based viewId(without iterator)?

Comment: I tried doing that and it works ..

Answer (score 0):

I remember this issue from the Oracle forums and I am not sure declarative components can be stamped (which is how af:iterator lays out its children). Can you try af:forEach?

Frank

Comment: Hi Frank,I tried initially with <af:forEach> but i found some performance issue while using <af:forEach>. The issue is <af:forEach> is trying to execute even if the jspx page(declarative component to be specific) in which it is declared is not rendered. So, tried switching to <af:iterator> but facing the above issue with that.